# Cloud Foundry eclipse integration error Message

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

I've install my CF on http://paas.azure4j.us

Now I want to use an eclipse plugin for CF , but when I add my CF server an error occured it said

**The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts**

But it works when I test it to api.vcap.me / my local CF.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this issue , so I edit my cloud_controller.yml and uaa.yml on 
~/cloudfoundry/.deployment/devbox/config

Then change uaa uri at http://uaa.cloudfoundry.com to http://paas.azure4j.us:8080/ to redirect it to own uaa.

Thanks for all solutions :))

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar issue addressed in a git change;

https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-cloudfoundry/pull/2

I am not really an Eclipse user, so this is a bit of a stab in the dark!

Answer (score 0):

I think Dan is correct here. At the moment you create your Cloud Foundry connection against 'localhost' (which doesn't make much sense from an Eclipse point-of-view) and in the new panel you specify your actual API target, username, password etc. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: I check about username and password via vmc client , It works.
Then I specify my api target,username and password into forms after first step , but it said "Wrong username and password" . 
Try check this : paas.azure4j.us 
It should be appear on browser . 
But on eclipse it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to your Cloud Foundry instant without any problem using STS. First I used vmc to register for a account. Once I registered an account, I went to STS and on the server tab I right clicked, and choose Cloud Foundry from my vmware folder.

When you choose the Cloud Foundry option on the server tab, keep the Server's host name the same (which is localhost). Give a name to your Server Name and keep the Server runtime environment the same as well. Click Next to move to the next screen. On the next screen you should see Email, Password and URL. Email and password are pretty straight forward and those should be your information which you registered with your Cloud Foundry instance. For the URL section, click on the Manage Cloud... button and then the Add... button. You should get a window popup which have Name and URL. For name put whatever name you want and for URL put in "http://paas.azure4j.us", then click on Finish. Now you have your custom Cloud URL added to the list so go ahead and click on the OK button again. Now you should be on the New Server window where you have the Email, Password and URL options. For the URL option go ahead and choose the newly added url you just created and then click on "Validate Account" to see if everything is validated. You should get a "Account information is valid" message. then click on Next and continue with the wizard until you are done and you have your Cloud Foundry instance added to your servers list.

Again I have performed the same exact steps I mentioned above and I was able to have your Cloud Foundry instance added to my servers tab.

Comment: So that's work on STS but it doesn't on eclipse .. maybe any other update version of the CF plugin on eclipse ..